# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Not a JPEG file

Tags: php, jpeg, fpdf

//$qus_img is empty

//error is in fpdf.php file

```
$qus_imga = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($qus_img);
$pic = getImage($qus_imga);

function getImage($dataURI)
{
    $img = explode(',',$dataURI,2);
    $pic = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.$img[1];
    $type = explode("/", explode(':', substr($dataURI, 0, strpos($dataURI, ';')))[1])[1]; // get the image type
    if ($type=="png"||$type=="jpeg"||$type=="gif") return array($pic, $type);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: is this code in sequence?

Comment: HERE IS THE CODE. LINE NO 62 https://pastebin.com/9CFV5aHG

Comment: I've never used `fpdf` but a quick look at the documentation http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm suggests that you supply an image name rather than a data string and I'm confused by the line `$pic = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.$img[1];`

Comment: actuallt i also dont know that whether the part which i am sending you is causing problem or which part causing pronblem.....my image was in png format while i uploaded it

Comment: if it was a png when you uploaded then using `data:image/jpeg;base64` would seem non-sensical would it not? Rather that would be `data:image/png;base64`

Comment: i tried that too. didnt worked

Comment: but have you seen examples of using image data like this (ie: `$pic = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.$img[1];` ) as the image source? The documentation uses `logo.png` or http://www.....someimage.jpg` etc

Comment: @RamRaider $img[1] give an image file to it..

Comment: `$img[1] give an image file to it` ?? do you mean a filename, such as `photo.png`? or a string like `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAA.........`?

Comment: @RamRaider its a filname with png or jpg as extension. let me start from the biginning and thanks for ur time bro

Comment: what value ( give example ) does the database column `'qus_img'` hold ?

Comment: $qus_img displaying that  it has nothing inside it....i will start from the beginning and if i face any problem,,i will write here

Comment: Could you please add some context to the question? For example, what you are trying to accomplish and what you have done to find a solution. SO isn't a code debugging site, so pasting only code is discouraged, thanks